# Keep Latin Modern as the font used inside math equations

Tags: fonts, fontspec, polyglossia, hebrew, math-fonts

In a Hebrew document, I changed the fonts as in the MWE below.

The thing is that when I have some text typed inside `\text{…}`, the font used to print it is not the font used for math.

How do I fix it?

I tried the `no-math` for fontspec but it doesn't help.

The output now:

[image: image 01]

whereas I want the "sec" to be printed with "Latin Modern Math":

[image: image 02]

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}[Script=Latin, Language=English]
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Math} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}
\begin{document}
אבג דהו $\Delta t=1\ \text{sec}$ זחט יכל.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not be using `\text` for this, it does not do what you think. For typesetting numbers and units use the `siunitx` package. Note for example that `\ ` is the wrong space between number and unit

Comment: @daleif Hmm no directly related, but loading the siunitx anywhere in the preamble gives the error "Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package color after bidi package. Please load package color before bidi package, and then try to run xelatex on your document again." Is there a known problem with these two packages?

Comment: on the other hand I cannot test any of your code as I don't have any of the fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `\mathrm` instead of \text.  This defaults to the main document font, but you can change it with `\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}`.  Also use `~` for a non-breaking space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error to use the wrong font for the current language.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}[Script=Latin, Language=English]
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}

\begin{document}
אבג דהו $\Delta t=1\mathrm{~sec}$ זחט יכל.
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

In practice, you probably want to make commands for this, such as `\sec` or `\unit{s}`, but at that point you might seriously consider `siunitx`.  You will seriously thank yourself later for using semantic markup that lets you change the formatting of your units or your vectors in a single place.  Otherwise, hunting down all the `\mathrm` commands that format units, and only those that do, will be a major headache when you have to change it later.

i took the liberty of adding a command to stop you from trying to display Hebrew in a font that doesn’t support it, and to automatically rescale the fonts to the same x-height.

### Side Notes

By the way, I answered the question as asked, but this isn’t a selection of fonts I would use by choice.  You might get some more harmonious-looking traditional fonts with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error to use the wrong font for the current language.
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
% The Culmus fonts are available at https://culmus.sourceforge.io/download.html
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Frank Ruehl CLM}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathrm{TeX Gyre Schola}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}

\begin{document}
אבג דהו $\Delta t=1\mathrm{~sec}$ זחט יכל.
\end{document}
```

[image: Frank Ruehl CLM + Schola sample]

This uses the fonts from [the Culmus Project.](https://culmus.sourceforge.io/download.html)

Or, if you want to stay with Arial and use a math font that matches it better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error to use the wrong font for the current language.
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathrm{fira Sans}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}

\begin{document}
אבג דהו $\increment t=1\mathrm{~sec}$ זחט יכל.
\end{document}
```

[image: Fira sample]

(There is also [a fork of Fira, [FiraGO](https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraGO), that supports Hebrew.)

Or, a good companion font for Computer Modern might be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error to use the wrong font for the current language.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
% Frank Ruhl Libre is available from:
% https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/fonts/display-font-charmap.php?fnt=FrankRuhlLibre
\defaultfontfeatures[FrankRuhlLibre]{ UprightFont = *-Light ,
                                      BoldFont = *-Medium ,
                                      Extension = .ttf ,
                                      Scale = 0.85 }

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{FrankRuhlLibre}[Script=Hebrew, Language=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\emph{ אבג דהו $\Delta t=1\mathrm{~sec}$ זחט יכל}

אבג דהו $ \Delta t=1\mathrm{~sec}$ זחט יכל.
\end{document}
```

[image: Frank Ruhl Libre + Latin Modern sample]

Where you can download the Hebrew font [from OpenSiddur.](https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/fonts/display-font-charmap.php?fnt=FrankRuhlLibre)

As a historical aside, Hayyim Selig Slonimski, a leader of the nineteenth-century Maskilim and one of the first to publish scientific works in Hebrew, [used Drugulin in the body of his books published in Warsaw.](https://archive.org/details/maamarehokhmahme00slon/page/n2/mode/2up)  That would be an unusual choice today!  (But if you were inclined to, the Taamey Ashkenaz font from Culmus with Times is a close approximation.)

### Post-Post-Script

As requested, an example using `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error to use the wrong font for the current language.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[mode=math,
            propagate-math-font=true,
            reset-math-version=false
           ]{siunitx}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}
\setboldmathrm{LM Roman 10 Bold}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\emph{ אבג דהו $\Delta t=\qty{1}{\second}$ זחט יכל} \\
אבג דהו
\( \Delta t=\qty{1}{\second} \)
זחט יכל.
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad font sample, with working \emph.]

I turned off the `reset-math-version` package option because the redefinition of `\emph` suggests you’re using `\boldmath` and want it to propagate to your units.  You might want to `\setboldmathrm` to make this work properly.

You can also reduce the spacing in some circumstances with the `tight-spacing` option, or use a font other than `\mathrm` with the `unit-font-command=` option.

Comment: I'd say `~` is too large as a unit space, `\,` would be better. BTW, I don;t have the hebrew fonts from any of your examples, do you mind testing `siunitx` with your example (per OPs comment above).

Comment: @daleif Okay, added an example with `siunitx`.

Comment: @Davislor I couldn't ask for a more elaborated answer. Beautiful.  But, I just checked your first MWE, and tried to change `mathrm{sec}` to `mathbf{sec}` and nothing is changed. Why is that?

Comment: @Davislor the selection of fonts was just for demonstration reasons, picking a font (Arial) that should be available to the preponderance of the users here.

Comment: @tush Because I erroneously copied `\setmathrm{Latin Modern Math}` from the question, which I should have corrected to `\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}`. i said so above, but neglected to do so in the MWE itself.

Comment: @tush At that point, you want to be using `siunitx` with the `unit-font-command=\mathbf` option, not writing `\matbf=` all over the place. It would be impossible to find and change all of the unit formatting, and only the unit formatting, later, if you just write `\mathbf`.

Comment: @Davislor I asked about `mathbf` in case that I want to type vectors, for example.

Comment: @tush `\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`.  If you ever need to change your vector notation to ***v*** (ISO style) or *v⃗*, or use the `\symbfup` alphabet from `unicode-math` to take the symbols from the math rather than the text font, you will thank yourself for using semantic markup.

Comment: @Davislor which leads me to ask — what is the difference between Latin Modern Roman and Latin Modern Math? Seems like they are just the same, except that bold face is not available in the latter.

Comment: @tush Latin Modern Roman is the text font. It has many features that aren’t present in the math font, such as optical sizes, ligatures and kerning. Latin Modern Math is an OpenType math font, with a large number of extra features and symbols. There are bold letters in it, as part of the Mathematical Unicode Symbols unicode block. In `unicode-math` with the default settings, you can test the difference between `\mathit{iff}` (the word *iff*, in the italic text font) and `\symit{iff}` (kerned as the product of variables *i*, *f* and *f*, using themath symbols from Latin Modern Math.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139097/discussion-between-tush-and-davislor).

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\newfontfamily\lmmath{Latin Modern Math}
\NewCommandCopy{\oldtext}{\text}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\text}{m}{\oldtext{\lmmath #1}}
```

Add these to preamble.
[image]

Comment: That works, but is there an other way of doing it without introducing a new font family?

Comment: You should read the `amstext` document. The `\text` macro allows the user to insert “normal text” into math formulas. If you must use `\text`, this is the better solution I can think of at present. Or it's possible that you don't know the function of `\text` very well. Instead of typesetting with mathematical font, it's to insert the normal text in the normal text font.